# How do I get the value of alert in my sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, flash-message

Hi currently debugging my sessions controller to get the flash message upon login failed.

in my sessions controller i have the following

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :handle_failed_login, :only => :new

  private
  def handle_failed_login
    ap "================"
    session[:activate_user] = true
    ap  session["flash"]
  end
end
```

session["flash"] returns this

```
{
    "discard" => [],
    "flashes" => {
        :alert => "Your account has expired due to inactivity. Please contact the site administrator."
    }
}
```

How can i get the value of alert in my controller?

I tried doing this `session["flash"]["flashes"]` but it didnt work.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Typically you access the flash via the `flash` helper, eg

```
flash[:alert]
```

The fact that the flash is stored inside the session is just an implementation detail.